# Android Studio Java: How to make a button break a while loop

Tags: java, android

I have question how to make button to break while loop. I don't have idea that this method exist at all.

For example i have while loop:

```
while(x==10000){
  x++;
}

void onClick(view v){

    // break the while loop 
}
```

And i want to make a button, **that when i clicked it i break the while loop** and get x value. e.g x=9834. Ofc i want this button to most advanced function. I appreciate if you paste me code, how to make it. Thanks a lot for help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply add another condition to break the `while` loop, that you control from your button :

```
boolean keepGoing = true;
while ((x==10000) && (keepGoing)) {
  x++;
}

void onClick(view v){
    keepGoing = false;
}
```

Comment: actually your code wouldn't work without adding sleep inside while.

Comment: @SergeyNeskoromny It would indeed depend of the speed at which the loop is executed as well as how fast the user clicks on the button. Having a while loop with a simple increment isn't an efficient way to `wait for something`, however this solution still fulfills the OP needs (interrupt a loop on click of a button)

Comment: Thanks a lot for help. It was really easy, that i didn't take it to consideration.